# Shared Preference problem in android app

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

in my app the first activity is a sign in page. In the edit boxes i am typing the user name and password. Those values are been move to an api and in return i am getting the userid from the server as an xml file.

I am parsing the xml file and storing the value in shared preferrence as follows

```
SharedPreferences.Editor IdEditor = Id.edit();
IdEditor.putString("useridValue", chap.getid());
IdEditor.commit();
```

And in the next time when the user opens the app i want to check whether it is already signed i or not. How to check this using the value stored in Shared preference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is your Id class extending `SharedPreferences` ?

maybe

String userId = Id.getString("useridValue");

If your preference is stored in the default preference then you can

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

String userId = prefs.getString("useridValue");
```

on a side note you shouldn't really use a capital I on the IdEditor variable it should probably be idEditor

Answer (score 0):

Check whether this entry already exist in shared preference, using:

```
id.containskey("useridvalue")
```